# Command line parameter to change gmapping resolution

Tags: navigation, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have another question with gmapping, is there a parameter that can be set at runtime that will change the resolution of the map generated?
Also is there a paramter to set the size of the map generated?

I am kind of looking for something like this:

rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping scan:=base_scan resolution=1 width=200 height=200

But this doesn't work. I don't want the occupancy grid to be 4k X 4k.
Thanks,
BM

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9828/command-line-parameter-to-change-gmapping-resolution/) by [BlackManta](https://answers.ros.org/users/428/blackmanta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2011-04-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can set the [gmapping ROS parameters](http://www.ros.org/wiki/gmapping#Parameters) on the command line using the _PARAM_NAME:=foo See documentation of [ROS commandline arguments for Private Parameters](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Remapping%20Arguments) on the wiki.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2